# SQL запрос в несколько таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Здрасте друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, такой вопрос, нужно извлечь данные из нескольких таблиц:

из таблицы product нужны данные из столбцов prod_id, price, name, sku

из таблицы product_special нужны данные из столбцов price

из таблицы product_description нужны данные из столбцов desc, cat

2 таблицы пока что получается

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN product_description using(product_id);") or die(mysql_error());
```

а вот остальное не получаеться

Comment: Приведите полную структуру БД, образец данных и в каком виде вы хотите увидеть результат. Приведенной информации не достаточно для написания запроса

Comment: Таблицы связанны между собой или это все разные данные? Т.е. данные вытягиваются из одной а другие ее дополняю?

Comment: Разобрался уже, спасибо всем!

Answer (score 0):

Если количество полей одинаковое необходимо, то можно использовать простой UNION

```
SELECT label1 FROM product
UNION
SELECT label2 FROM product_special
UNION
SELECT label3 FROM product_description
```

Comment: а вывести как данные в цикле?

Comment: и выдает ошибку "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Да, виноват, попробуйте заменить UNION на INNER JOIN

Comment: SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM product_special INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM product_description

Выдало такое: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM oc_product_special INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM oc_product_description' at line 1

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl просто полистайте вопросы-ответы, посмотрите примеры запросов ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+join (это я к тому, что слово select обычно одно пишется и потом во from несколько таблиц с условиями)

Comment: Спасибо , буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, спасибо всем!

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT
  p.product_id AS p_id,
  p.sku AS p_sku,
  p.upc AS p_upc,
  p.quantity AS p_quantity,
  p.price AS p_price,
  p.image AS p_image, 
  pd.name AS p_name,
  cd.name AS p_category,
  ps.price AS p_spacial

FROM oc_product p


    LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_category_description cd ON p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
") or die(mysql_error());
```